# Make only top ViewController rotate

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, orientation, viewcontroller

I have a question regarding the following. My app is mainly in portrait mode but for a few viewcontrollers, I want to make it rotatable to landscape mode. The code works perfectly for the topviewcontroller, the one that I want to make rotatable, but since it is a sort of image popup viewcontroller, you can also see the controller in the back also rotate. And I don't want that. I just want to make the popup viewcontroller rotatable. What can I do so that only the topviewcontroller rotates?

I already have the following code in AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let rootViewController = self.topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: window?.rootViewController) {
        if (rootViewController.responds(to: Selector(("canRotate")))) {

            return .allButUpsideDown;
        }
    }

    return .portrait;
}

private func topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: UIViewController!) -> UIViewController? {
    if (rootViewController == nil) { return nil }
    if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UITabBarController).selectedViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self)) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: (rootViewController as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController)
    } else if (rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil) {
        return topViewControllerWithRootViewController(rootViewController: rootViewController.presentedViewController)
    }
    return rootViewController
}
```

And in my viewcontrollers file:

```
@IBAction func didDismissButtonPress(sender: UIButton) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { () -> Void in
        UIDevice.current.setValue(Int(UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait.rawValue), forKey: "orientation")
    }
}
```

In advance, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Are you overriding viewWillTransition() anywhere in your code? I should think you need to override this through your view controller hierarchy to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentcontainer/1621466-viewwilltransition

Comment: I think if the system manages the transition and if you present some controller over the other viewcontroller's context, they will be handled the same. Override the viewWillTransition method, as @Sparky mentioned in the back and front controller also.

Answer (score 1):

First go to Target's setting -> General Tab -> Deployment Info section, in device orientation select portrait, landscape left and landscape right. Now for your case in extension of your viewcontroller below pop,

```
extension BelowVC {
  override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait
  }
}
```

Similarly you can restrict any of the VC's from rotating.

Comment: Sorry doesn't work. Previous viewcontroller still rotates. Hard nut to crack, haven't found a solution for it on the internet.

Comment: I will try it to implement, just a moment.

Comment: Maybe you have some something about this code to help with the answer: controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen   This is in the seque initiation from the previous VC